# Adobe Flex 4: Alert Title shows localized Asian Language correctly, but the Alert message does not

Tags: apache-flex, localization, internationalization, flex4, adobe

I'm creating an alert popup within an Adobe Flex 4 project using the following:

```
Alert.show(resourceManager.getString('myresource', 'ErrorMessage'), resourceManager.getString('myResource', 'ErrorMessageTitle'), Alert.OK|Alert.CANCEL,this,onExitSuccess,null,Alert.CANCEL);
```

When my language is of Asian origin (Japanese, Korean, Chinese, etc) the title appears correctly on the Alert, but the message does not.  I'm seeing the correct localization values **EVERYWHERE ELSE** in my application except the Alert popup and in one other instance on a mx:Checkbox control.

I've checked my app and the strings are being returned from the resourceManager correctly but just aren't rendering to the screen.  Does anyone have any insight as to what might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you just missed right bracket in the first of `getString` calls:

```
Alert.show(resourceManager.getString('myresource', 'ErrorMessage'), resourceManager.getString('myResource', 'ErrorMessageTitle'), Alert.OK|Alert.CANCEL,this,onExitSuccess,null,Alert.CANCEL);
```

**Update:**

Ok as far as there is no typo in question I suppose the problem is in font embedding. Try to set the same font style for alert body as in alert title and check the result.

Comment: That was just a typo.  I wish it was that easy.

Comment: @Shawn I've added an other version of my answer :)

Comment: I'm looking at the font embedding now but Im not sure thats the problem since I have other Asian text being displayed in the project.  When I replace the Alert message text with something that I can confirm is displaying, it's still missing.

Comment: Can you set your expected Asian text in `Alert.show()` parameters explicitly without using resource manager for testing purposes? What is the result?

Comment: Same result.  Alert Title shows but the content does not.  Same result with the mx:Checkbox.  I figured it was an issue with these two classes since the rest of the project displays the Asian correctly.  This project was originally written in Flex 3 and upgraded to Flex 4 but did not upgrade to the TLF.

Comment: So the problem is definitely in fonts. If I'll debug this application I'll start with CheckBox with Asian string without resource manager and try different font styles.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the problem is the font.  I've replaced the string that isn't showing with text that is showing in other parts of the app and I get the same result.